# Round a floating-point number down to the nearest integer?

Tags: python, floating-point, integer, rounding

I want to take a floating-point number and round it down to the nearest integer. However, if it's not a whole, I *always* want to round down the variable, regardless of how close it is to the next integer up. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: A possible difficulty is that IEEE floating point formats can represent numbers so large that the grandularity is larger than 1. So that, while you can round x down rounding x+1 down will not give you the result you expect.

Comment: Please post some examples.

Comment: "Round down" and "round to the nearest integer" are two different things.

Answer (score 215):

```
int(x)
```

Conversion to integer will truncate (towards 0.0), like `math.trunc`.
For non-negative numbers, this is downward.

If your number can be negative, this will round the *magnitude* downward, unlike `math.floor` which rounds towards -Infinity, making a lower value.  (Less positive or more negative).

Python integers are arbitrary precision, so even very large floats can be represented as integers.  (Unlike in other languages where this idiom could fail for floats larger than the largest value for an integer type.)

Comment: int(0.6) = 0 rather than 1

Comment: @HelinWang That's exactly what OP asked for.

Comment: This seems like the most Pythonic approach.

Comment: This works well for positive numbers, but negative numbers will be rounded up: `int(-23.3) == 23`

Comment: and does not work for number beyond the integer range such as 600851475143, it will basically flag a memory error.

Comment: @MuyideIbukun python? beyond the integer range?

Comment: @MuyideIbukun `int(-1E99)` gives (at my side) `-999999999999999967336168804116691273849533185806555472917961779471295845921727862608739868455469056L` which looks pretty ok to me.

Comment: @AlexRiley While you are mathematically correct, usually the "nearest lower integer" a human wants is towards 0 and not towards -inf.  If your account balance is -23.3M$ you will rather think of having -23M than having -24M, right?  Same is true if you have -23.9M;  You will still pretend it's only -23M as long as you can ;)

Comment: @Tino But if you had $23.1M, you would definitely want to round it up to $24; so I don't think your example applies here:)

Comment: I like this solution much less than `math.floor`: one should know how `int` function works to see rounding down happens. The solution also relies on a detail of implementation of `int` function (even though it's unlikely to change). `math.floor` on the other hand is explicit: just looking at it is enough to be sure rounding down will happen.

Comment: As Mikhail said in accordance with Python Zen: Explicit is better than implicit. That's it about using int for rounding values.

Comment: @MikhailGerasimov: This isn't even the same as `math.floor`.  Conversion to integer is done with truncation toward 0, like in C.  I edited the answer to make it clear to future readers exactly what this does (and introduce readers to the concepts of rounding directions, since if they knew about floor vs. trunc they'd probably not have had to google this.)  This involved rewriting the entire text outside the code, so Ghostwriter you might want to rephrase some of it if you think different wording would help future readers the most.

Comment: int(0.9999999999999999) >>> 0; however, int(0.99999999999999999) >>> 1.  Surely this is an issue given the OP question.

Answer (score 85):

One of these should work:

```
import math
math.trunc(1.5)
> 1
math.trunc(-1.5)
> -1
math.floor(1.5)
> 1
math.floor(-1.5)
> -2
```

Comment: The output from `math.trunc` is an integer, while the output of `math.floor` is a float.

Comment: @evedovelli: Not really anymore. `type(math.floor(1.51)) -> int` and `type(math.trunc(1.51)) -> int` as of `python 3.6.0`

Comment: These options are more explicit than "int(x)" and hence are more Pythonic.

Answer (score 55):

```
x//1
```

The `//` operator returns the floor of the division. Since dividing by 1 doesn't change your number, this is equivalent to floor but no import is needed. 
Notes:

1. This returns a float
2. This rounds towards -∞

Comment: Nice addition.  `int(-1.1) == -1` while `-1.1//1 == -2.0` however `decimal.Decimal('-1.1')//1 == decimal.Decimal('-1')` (as documented, claim 2 isn't true for `decimal`), so relying on how `//` behaves is not fully stable, even today.

Answer (score 34):

To get floating point result simply use:

```
round(x-0.5)
```

It works for negative numbers as well.

Comment: but it's wrong for already rounded numbers like 1:

1 - 0.5 = 0.5 and round(0.5) = 0, so 1 will be transformed to 0

Answer (score 31):

I think you need a floor function :

[math.floor(x)](http://docs.python.org/2/library/math.html)

Comment: in python 2 it returns a float while in python 3 it returns int

Comment: int(math.floor(x)) or float(math.floor(x))

Answer (score 9):

a lot of people say to use `int(x)`, and this works ok for most cases, but there is a little problem. If OP's result is:

```
x = 1.9999999999999999
```

it will round to

```
x = 2
```

after the 16th 9 it will round. This is not a big deal if you are sure you will never come across such thing. But it's something to keep in mind.

Comment: That is because `1.9999999999999999` is actually equal to `2.0` in the internal float64 representation. I. e. it's already rounded as soon as it is parsed into a float, as a 64 bit float cannot represent that many significant digits. You can verify that with evaluating `1.9999999999999999 == 2.0`. And if you suspect that the equals operation does some rounding on floats, you can compare the binary representation with `struct.pack("d", 1.9999999999999999) == struct.pack("d", 2.0)`, which is also equal.

Comment: And if that's exactly your point, then I don't see what's wrong with `int()`. The value is already 2.0 and it will convert it happily into 2.

Comment: If OP's (or whomever reads this in the future) intention is to use the nearest integer ( and not the round-up value) for whatever reason, then it would be something to keep in mind.

Comment: @lokilindo But this has nothing to do with `int()`, it solely has to do with an **improper use of `float`**, as `1.9999999999999999` is rounded up to `2.0` **at compile time** (while `int()` is called on execution time).  If you use the right data type for the variable, everything works as expected:
 `int(decimal.Decimal('1.9999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999'))` gives `1`

Answer (score 6):

If you don't want to import math, you could use:

`int(round(x))`

Here's a piece of documentation:

```
>>> help(round)
Help on built-in function round in module __builtin__:

round(...)
    round(number[, ndigits]) -> floating point number

    Round a number to a given precision in decimal digits (default 0 digits).
    This always returns a floating point number.  Precision may be negative.
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Next time you'll get a better reception if you write proper code (close parenthesis), and give some documentation.

Comment: `round` was already discussed and rejected as an answer when this question was asked a year ago. OP wants `math.floor`.

Answer (score 3):

If you working with numpy, you can use the following solution which also works with negative numbers (it's also working on arrays)

```
import numpy as np
def round_down(num):
    if num < 0:
        return -np.ceil(abs(num))
    else:
        return np.int32(num)
round_down = np.vectorize(round_down)
```

---

```
round_down([-1.1, -1.5, -1.6, 0, 1.1, 1.5, 1.6])
> array([-2., -2., -2.,  0.,  1.,  1.,  1.])
```

I think it will also work if you just use the `math` module instead of `numpy` module.

Answer (score 3):

Just make round(x-0.5) this will always return the next rounded down Integer value of your Float. You can also easily round up by do round(x+0.5)

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if you solved this, but I just stumble upon this question. If you want to get rid of decimal points, you could use int(x) and it will eliminate all decimal digits. Theres no need to use round(x).

Answer (score -2):

It may be very simple, but couldn't you just round it up then minus 1?
For example:

```
number=1.5
round(number)-1
> 1
```

Comment: This gives the wrong answer for whole integers. For instance, 2.0 rounded up is 2, and if you subtract 1 you get the incorrect result 1.

Comment: @PascalCuoq I don't understand your problem. Do you want 1.0 as the result? Because OP clearly wanted to round then number off to the nearest `integer`.

Comment: @bad_keypoints I don't think that the OP wants to round 2.0 to 1.

Comment: @PascalCuoq sorry, I just looked back at the answer in comment thread of which we are.

Answer (score -7):

I used this code where you subtract 0.5 from the number and when you round it, it is the original number rounded down.

> round(a-0.5)

Comment: What's the difference from [this existed answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29651462/5376789)?