# How to round to 2 decimals with Python?

Tags: python, rounding

I am getting a lot of decimals in the output of this code (Fahrenheit to Celsius converter).

My code currently looks like this:

```
def main():
    printC(formeln(typeHere()))

def typeHere():
    global Fahrenheit
    try:
        Fahrenheit = int(raw_input("Hi! Enter Fahrenheit value, and get it in Celsius!\n"))
    except ValueError:
        print "\nYour insertion was not a digit!"
        print "We've put your Fahrenheit value to 50!"
        Fahrenheit = 50
    return Fahrenheit

def formeln(c):
    Celsius = (Fahrenheit - 32.00) * 5.00/9.00
    return Celsius

def printC(answer):
    answer = str(answer)
    print "\nYour Celsius value is " + answer + " C.\n"



main()
```

So my question is, how do I make the program round every answer to the 2nd decimal place?

Comment: A small remark regarding your code. There is no reason to have the Fahrenheit value kept as a global, it is enough (and better) to transmit it as a parameter to your functions.
So, remove the "global Fahrenheit" line.
In the formeln function, rename the parameter to the function "Fahreinheit" formeln(Fahreinheit).
As for the rounding, you can just use the "%" parameters to display only the first 2 digits, and it should be rounded for these digits. There is no effect to the number of digits provided in the formula in formeln.

Answer (score 1057, accepted):

You can use the [`round`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#round) function, which takes as its first argument the number and the second argument is the precision after the decimal point.

In your case, it would be:

```
answer = str(round(answer, 2))
```

Comment: "[Note The behavior of `round()` for floats can be surprising: for example, `round(2.675, 2)` gives `2.67` instead of the expected `2.68`.](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#round)"

Comment: **note**: this changes the value of answer. If you simply want to round for display, go with the answer of @Johnsyweb - https://stackoverflow.com/a/20457284/1498405

Comment: @Johnsyweb I'm trying it today, year's after original post and it looks working as expected. Seems round() evolved over time. See below:
round(1.379, 2) -> 1.38
round(1.372, 2) -> 1.37
round(1.375, 2) -> 1.38

Comment: @NightFurry: That has not been my experience: https://ideone.com/UxO8E9 (Python (cpython 2.7.13)) and https://ideone.com/gCFGjg (Python 3 nbc (python 3.4))

Comment: `num = 1345000; round(num / 1000000, 2)` gives me 1.34 instead of 1.35, using python 3.6

Comment: @NightFurry, you need to try `2.675`, not `1.375`. Still doesn't work with `Python 3.8.2`.

Comment: WARNING ! on python3:
`str(round(5.000, 2)) => 5.0`
`str(round(5, 2)) => 5`

Comment: round(2.675,2) gives 2.67, because 2.675 cannot be represented exactly by computer as the nature of float number. Run `from decimal import Decimal; Decimal.from_float(2.675)` , you can find 2.675 is actually stored as 2.67499999999999982236431605997495353221893310546875. I found [this link](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html#tut-fp-issues) is useful.

Comment: To avoid surprises, `str.format()` is a decent way, I think

Comment: @MarkDickinson so what's your solution?

Answer (score 215):

Using [`str.format()`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.format)'s [syntax](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#format-string-syntax) to *display* `answer` with two decimal places (without altering the underlying value of `answer`):

```
def printC(answer):
    print("\nYour Celsius value is {:0.2f}ºC.\n".format(answer))
```

Where:

- `:` introduces the [format spec](https://docs.python.org/reference/lexical_analysis.html#grammar-token-format-spec)
- `0` enables sign-aware zero-padding for numeric types
- `.2` sets the [precision](https://docs.python.org/library/string.html#grammar-token-precision) to `2`
- `f` displays the number as a fixed-point number

Comment: This is the most useful answer IMO - keeps the actual value intact and is simple to implement! Thanks!

Comment: Not sure why, but '{:0.2f}'.format(0.5357706) gives me '0.54' (python 3.6)

Comment: @NoamPeled: Why shouldn't it? `0.5357...` is closer to `0.54` than to `0.53`, so rounding to `0.54` makes sense.

Comment: `"{:0.2f}".format(1.755)` -> 1.75
`"{:0.2f}".format(1.7551)` -> 1.76

- However, I would have both expected to equal 1.76.

Comment: (Python Version: 3.6.10)

Comment: @Janothan floating point values are not precise. Try `"{:0.20f}".format(1.755)` and you'll see why the value with two decimal places is displayed as `1.75`.

Comment: What does the sign-aware zero-padding here mean? I get that it'll be padded with leading zeros if the number is not long enough, but since there are no minimum length requirements here (like `{:05.2f}`), what does the zero do?

Comment: @jackz314 6.5 years (and many Python versions) after I wrote this answer, I forget why I thought the zero to be worth including.

Answer (score 93):

Most answers suggested `round` or `format`. `round` sometimes rounds up, and in my case I needed the *value* of my variable to be rounded down and not just displayed as such.

```
round(2.357, 2)  # -> 2.36
```

I found the answer here: [How do I round a floating point number up to a certain decimal place?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4518641/how-to-round-off-a-floating-number)

```
import math
v = 2.357
print(math.ceil(v*100)/100)  # -> 2.36
print(math.floor(v*100)/100)  # -> 2.35
```

or:

```
from math import floor, ceil

def roundDown(n, d=8):
    d = int('1' + ('0' * d))
    return floor(n * d) / d

def roundUp(n, d=8):
    d = int('1' + ('0' * d))
    return ceil(n * d) / d
```

Comment: "values are rounded to the closest multiple of 10 to the power minus ndigits;" https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#round so no, round does not always round up, e.g. `round(2.354, 2)  # -> 2.35`

Comment: @PeteKirkham you are right, I edited my answer to make more sense and accurate.

Comment: Well, you should check your solution with negative values...
math.floor(0.5357706*100)/100 -> 0.53
math.floor(-0.5357706*100)/100 -> -0.54

Comment: -0.54 is the correct answer for rounding -0.5357706 down because it is a negative number, -0.54 < -0.53

Comment: I would use `10**d` instead of `int('1' + ('0' * d))`.

Answer (score 72):

If you just want to print the rounded result out, you can use the [f-strings](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/) introduced since Python 3.6. The syntax is the same as [`str.format()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format)'s [format string syntax](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-string-syntax), except you put a `f` in front of the literal string, and you put the variables directly in the string, within the curly braces.

`.2f` indicates rounding to two decimal places:

```
number = 3.1415926
print(f"The number rounded to two decimal places is {number:.2f}")
```

Output:

```
The number rounded to two decimal places is 3.14
```

Comment: This will round 39.555 to 39.55, which gives incorrect results if you expect the rounding to be 39.56

Comment: If anyone does not place the `f` after `.2`, a number like `14.426599999999999` will round to `1.4e+01`. As far as Python 3.8.6

Comment: @martin36, this is not an incorrect result, since 39.555 cannot be represented exactly in floating-point format, so Python will actually store the number 39.554999999999999...., which is correctly rounded to 39.55. If someone expects it to be rounded to 39.56, then the expectations are wrong IMHO. When working with floating-point numbers, you should be aware of these "inaccuracies", and either accept them or choose a different data type.

Answer (score 66):

You can use the round function.

```
round(80.23456, 3)
```

will give you an answer of 80.234

In your case, use

```
answer = str(round(answer, 2))
```

Answer (score 21):

You want to round your answer.

`round(value,significantDigit)` is the ordinary solution to do this, however this ***sometimes*** does not operate as one would expect from a math perspective when the digit immediately inferior (to the left of) the digit you're rounding to has a `5`.

Here's some examples of this unpredictable behavior:

```
>>> round(1.0005,3)
1.0
>>> round(2.0005,3)
2.001
>>> round(3.0005,3)
3.001
>>> round(4.0005,3)
4.0
>>> round(1.005,2)
1.0
>>> round(5.005,2)
5.0
>>> round(6.005,2)
6.0
>>> round(7.005,2)
7.0
>>> round(3.005,2)
3.0
>>> round(8.005,2)
8.01
```

Assuming your intent is to do the traditional rounding for statistics in the sciences, this is a handy wrapper to get the `round` function working as expected needing to `import` extra stuff like `Decimal`.

```
>>> round(0.075,2)

0.07

>>> round(0.075+10**(-2*6),2)

0.08
```

Aha! So based on this we can make a function...

```
def roundTraditional(val,digits):
   return round(val+10**(-len(str(val))-1), digits)
```

Basically this adds a really small value to the string to force it to round up properly on the unpredictable instances where it doesn't ordinarily with the `round` function when you expect it to.  A convenient value to add is `1e-X` where `X` is the length of the number string you're trying to use `round` on plus `1`.

The approach of using `10**(-len(val)-1)` was deliberate, as it the largest small number you can add to force the shift, while also ensuring that the value you add never changes the rounding even if the decimal `.` is missing.  I could use just `10**(-len(val))` with a condiditional `if (val>1)` to subtract `1` more... but it's simpler to just always subtract the `1` as that won't change much the applicable range of decimal numbers this workaround can properly handle.  This approach will fail if your values reaches the limits of the type, this will fail, but for nearly the entire range of valid decimal values it should work.

So the finished code will be something like:

```
def main():
    printC(formeln(typeHere()))

def roundTraditional(val,digits):
    return round(val+10**(-len(str(val))-1))

def typeHere():
    global Fahrenheit
    try:
        Fahrenheit = int(raw_input("Hi! Enter Fahrenheit value, and get it in Celsius!\n"))
    except ValueError:
        print "\nYour insertion was not a digit!"
        print "We've put your Fahrenheit value to 50!"
        Fahrenheit = 50
    return Fahrenheit

def formeln(c):
    Celsius = (Fahrenheit - 32.00) * 5.00/9.00
    return Celsius

def printC(answer):
    answer = str(roundTraditional(answer,2))
    print "\nYour Celsius value is " + answer + " C.\n"

main()
```

...should give you the results you expect.

You can also use the [decimal](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html) library to accomplish this, but the wrapper I propose is simpler and may be preferred in some cases.

---

**Edit:** Thanks [Blckknght](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1405065/blckknght) for pointing out that the `5` fringe case occurs only for certain values [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31818050/python-2-7-round-number-to-nearest-integer/38239574?noredirect=1#comment63901388_38239574).

Comment: This doesn't work for negative numbers e.g -4.625 evaluates to -4.62. Can you modify it to work for negative numbers?

Answer (score 21):

If you need **avoid floating point problem** on rounding numbers for accounting, you can use numpy round.

You need install numpy :

```
pip install numpy
```

and the code :

```
import numpy as np

print(round(2.675, 2))
print(float(np.round(2.675, 2)))
```

prints

```
2.67
2.68
```

You should use that if you manage money with legal rounding.

Comment: This does not work if the last digit is a 0. For example the number 39.90 will be rounded to 39.9

Comment: This method gives you a decimal value not a string. You should use @jackz314 if you want a string with the format you want

Comment: if running on pi, use the pi version: apt install python3-numpy

Comment: This doesn't work.
`np.round(2.665, 2)` returns `2.66` while `round(2.665, 2)` returns `2.67`.

Here is my solution. https://stackoverflow.com/a/53329223/6069907

Comment: @SamuelDauzon Of course I tried it on my local. I got my result on python 3.7(win10) and numpy 1.19.3.

Answer (score 13):

```
float(str(round(answer, 2)))
float(str(round(0.0556781255, 2)))
```

Answer (score 12):

If you need not only round result but elso do math operations with round result, then you can use `decimal.Decimal` https://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html

```
from decimal import Decimal, ROUND_DOWN

Decimal('7.325').quantize(Decimal('.01'), rounding=ROUND_DOWN)
Decimal('7.32')
```

Answer (score 11):

```
from decimal import Decimal, ROUND_HALF_UP

# Here are all your options for rounding:
# This one offers the most out of the box control
# ROUND_05UP       ROUND_DOWN       ROUND_HALF_DOWN  ROUND_HALF_UP
# ROUND_CEILING    ROUND_FLOOR      ROUND_HALF_EVEN  ROUND_UP

our_value = Decimal(16.0/7)
output = Decimal(our_value.quantize(Decimal('.01'), 
rounding=ROUND_HALF_UP))
print output
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer

Comment: ```decimal``` is not a built-in function so it really should not be the accepted answer.

Comment: For traditional rounding, it shouldn't be the accepted answer.

Comment: Also, please always show the output...

Comment: @jwal it’s a built-in module.

Answer (score 9):

Just use the formatting with %.2f which gives you rounding down to 2 decimals.

```
def printC(answer):
    print "\nYour Celsius value is %.2f C.\n" % answer
```

Answer (score 9):

You can use **round** operator for up to 2 decimal

```
num = round(343.5544, 2)
print(num) // output is 343.55
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use the string formatting operator of python "%".
"%.2f" means 2 digits after the decimal point.

```
def typeHere():
    try:
        Fahrenheit = int(raw_input("Hi! Enter Fahrenheit value, and get it in Celsius!\n"))
    except ValueError:
        print "\nYour insertion was not a digit!"
        print "We've put your Fahrenheit value to 50!"
        Fahrenheit = 50
    return Fahrenheit

def formeln(Fahrenheit):
    Celsius = (Fahrenheit - 32.0) * 5.0/9.0
    return Celsius

def printC(answer):
    print "\nYour Celsius value is %.2f C.\n" % answer

def main():
    printC(formeln(typeHere()))

main()
```

http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting

Answer (score 5):

To avoid surprising value from round() this is my approche:

```
Round = lambda x, n: eval('"%.'+str(int(n))+'f" % '+repr(int(x)+round(float('.'+str(float(x)).split('.')[1]),n)))

print(Round(2, 2))       # 2.00
print(Round(2.675, 2))   # 2.68
```

Comment: Isn't working for 0.625.

Comment: Please explain what you're trying to solve (what's *surprising*) and what your lambda does.

Answer (score 3):

Truncating to 2 digitis:

```py
somefloat = 2.23134133
truncated = int( somefloat * 100 ) / 100  # 2.23
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example that I used:

```
def volume(self):
    return round(pi * self.radius ** 2 * self.height, 2)

def surface_area(self):
    return round((2 * pi * self.radius * self.height) + (2 * pi * self.radius ** 2), 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
round(12.3956 - 0.005, 2)  # minus 0.005, then round.
```

The answer is from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29651462/8025086

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution I found so far, dunno why people ain't using it.

```
# Make sure the number is a float
a = 2324.55555
# Round it according to your needs
# dPoints is the decimals after the point
dPoints = 2
# this will round the float to 2 digits
a = a.__round__(dPoints)
if len(str(a).split(".")[1]) < dPoints:
    # But it will only keep one 0 if there is nothing,
    # So we add the extra 0s we need
    print(str(a)+("0"*(dPoints-1)))
else:
    print(a)
```

Comment: This is a complicated way to reimplement `"%.2f" % a`.

Answer (score 0):

As you want your answer in decimal number so you dont need to typecast your **answer** variable to str in printC() function.

and then use [printf-style String Formatting](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#old-string-formatting)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why, but '{:0.2f}'.format(0.5357706) gives me '0.54'.
The only solution that works for me (python 3.6) is the following:

```
def ceil_floor(x):
    import math
    return math.ceil(x) if x < 0 else math.floor(x)

def round_n_digits(x, n):
    import math
    return ceil_floor(x * math.pow(10, n)) / math.pow(10, n)

round_n_digits(-0.5357706, 2) -> -0.53 
round_n_digits(0.5357706, 2) -> 0.53
```

Comment: This is truncating, not rounding.

Comment: {:0.2f} rounded the value correctly. Your solution is not rounding.