# I need to create a BMI calculator however it does not round to two decimal places. I was wondering how to do so. This is my code so far in python

Tags: python

```
height = float(input("What is your height in meters?"))
weight = float(input("What is your weight in kg?"))

sum = weight/height/height

print('The sum is {0} divided by {1} divided by {1} equals {2}'.format(weight,height,sum))
```

Comment: I assume that you read the [documentation for `round`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#round). Which part of it do you have problems with?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python - how to round down to 2 decimals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20457038/python-how-to-round-down-to-2-decimals)

Comment: @Coldspeed: Was that at all helpful?

Answer (score 0):

Life will be easier for you, as a programmer, if you use **google**. And I mean no offence. In this case, just query for *python round*.

In this particular case, if you want to round a float called `BMD` to two decimal places then you would use the following expression,

```
round(BMD,2)
```

You might also be interested in how to use formatting to achieve a similar result. First I deliberately set `BMD` to a value that has only two decimal places. I can print it as-is but I have no control. In the second case, I set `BMD` to a value for quite a few decimal places but this time I limit the number of *output* decimal places.

In my opinion, it's safer to use `round` and then use the first formatting option because the second option could stumble with a value such as 345.22 (which occupies more than four columns overall).

```
>>> BMD = 5.21
>>> print ('BMD is {}'.format(BMD))
BMD is 5.21
>>> BMD = 5.213333333333333
>>> print ('BMD is {:4.2f}'.format(BMD))
BMD is 5.21
```