# decimal number represented with many digits when there are only 2

Tags: python, dataframe, floating-point, precision

I'm trying to output a decimal number that is saved in a pandas series object.

The number is 7.45. But when I output it it becomes 7.449999809265137. I need it to be 7.45. How do I access the exact number 7.45 and not a floating point value that approximates 7.45?

---series_data['High']
Symbols
PIH     7.45
TPNL    0.75
TURN    2.05
Name: 2018-01-02 00:00:00, dtype: float64

--- series_data['High']['PIH']
7.449999809265137

Comment: That's the number in your series.

Comment: but standard print ouputs 7.45 when i have it output the series though. not 7.449999809265137

Comment: Yes, so? `pandas` objects do a lot of formatting.

Comment: The floating-point format(s) used by most Python implementations are binary based and cannot represent 7.45 exactly. There is no way to represent 7.45 in a binary floating-point type. Your choices are to using the binary floating-point type and round output to two decimal digits after the decimal point or to use another format to represent the number, such as a character string, a scaled integer, or the `decimal` module.

Comment: Did you try `repr()`?

Comment: closely related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20457038/how-to-round-to-2-decimals-with-python. Just check this out and you should get the answer

Comment: tried repr(), didn't work. 
I"m forced to just format the output. But how does Series.toString() know how to output two decimal places? 
I have to use the following to get get the number showing properly: format(series_data['High']['PIH'],'.4f')

Answer (score 0):

As stated above, the number being held in memory is the number with many decimal places.  You may have reached that number while expecting to see 7.45 due to some **numerical precision** issue.  Representation of floating point numbers is not always exact.  For example:

```
>>> 0.1 + 0.2
0.30000000000000004
>>
```

You have a couple choices when you extract the number:  you could format it to 2 decimal places (and retain the full representation in memory), you could forcibly round it off and change what is in memory:

```
x = numpy.round(x, 2)   # will round x to 2 decimal places and save that value
```

Answer (score 0):

Floating points are *not* designed for precise values, but for measument data which inherently have a certain precision. Please read https://floating-point-gui.de/

For printing up to a certain precision use string formatting options like `%2f` % nr

Please don't round floating points