# how to pick up to 2 or 3 decimals with lists using python2?

Tags: list, python-2.7, decimal

I  am reading data from the robot's sensor. it gives this data as a list:

```
data:[1.0014142543, 0.4142543254, 4.5432544179]
```

I'd like to convert it like this format:

```
data:[1.00, 0.41, 4.54]
```

I am running it with python2.

I think  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20457038/how-to-round-to-2-decimals-with-python) post for one number.

any ideas or suggestions, it would be highly appreciated.

Comment: use `round(float, 2)`

Comment: no, this is a list, I already tried with it but not works. I am using round(float, 2)  with a float number. please try to implement it.

Comment: @Redhwan, what is wrong with the approach @Rakesh mentioned. You can try to do that for every element in list using `map()` like - `map(lambda x: round(x, 2), data)`

Comment: [round(item,2) for item in data]

Comment: Why do you want this? If this is just for display, use string formatting, not `round`ing. If you're going to perform further computations with the numbers, why would you want to throw away precision?

Comment: thank you all, this is enough for my purpose...> map(lambda x: round(x, 2), data), I don't think about it. thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering data as list ,

Using round :

```
>> data=[1.00, 0.41, 4.54]
>> [round(item,2) for item in data]
```

Using Float and Format:

```
>> [float(format(item,".2f")) for item in data]
```

Output :

```
[1.0, 0.41, 4.54]
```

Comment: redhatvicky, thank you so much. it is OK now.