# How to represent values float in 2 float point in python?

Tags: python, floating

I need to calculate values of type float, so, in python, 0.01 is not 0.01 but 0.10000000000000001 + some digits (referenced by python documentation Floating).

Ok, my function needs to calculate the number of coins for each value.

```
def calcula_moedas(resto):
        moedas = [0.5, 0.1, 0.05, 0.01]
        cont_moeda = {'0.5': 0, '0.1': 0, '0.05': 0, '0.01': 0}
        if resto > 0.00:
            for valor in moedas:
                while resto >= valor:
                    str_valor = str(valor)
                    cont_moeda[str_valor] += 1
                    resto = round(resto, 2) - valor
                    break
            return cont_moeda
        return cont_moeda
```

I tried to use round(resto, 2), round(resto, 10) and Decimal(resto), but the result is wrong yet.
Using `resto = round(resto, 2) - valor` the result is **0.04999999999999999** when I pass a values **0.15**.

Using Decimal the result is:

[Image for Decimal module](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aYfZ7.png)

How can I around this number so that the rounded number is 0.05?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to round to 2 decimals with Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20457038/how-to-round-to-2-decimals-with-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use:

```
resto = round(resto - valor, 2)
```