# Python: how to round an indexed number?

Tags: python, rounding

I have the following code snippet (from part of a Class):

```
def __init__(self):
    self.data_end = self.datas[0].end
    self.data_start = self.datas[0].start
```

Then, the following code:

```
def next_trans(self):
    if not self.position:
        if self.buy_signal > 0:
            size = int(self.getcash() / self.datas[0].start)
            self.log(f'BUY - Size: {size}, Cash: {self.getcash():.2f}, Start: {self.data_start[0]}, End: {self.data_end[0]}')
            self.start(size=size)
```

The problem I have is that the "Start" and "End" values are printing as long floating point numbers (e.g. 89.12999725341797).

I tried various ways to use round(), but with no success.  I get errors such as:

```
AttributeError: 'LineBuffer' object has no attribute 'round'
```

and

```
TypeError: type LineBuffer doesn't define __round__ method
```

How do I round the output to two decimal places (e.g. 89.13)?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: possibly duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20457038/how-to-round-to-2-decimals-with-python

Comment: You've already done for `self.getcash()` what is needed: `Start: {self.data_start[0]:.2f}, End: {self.data_end[0]:.2f}`

Comment: @Frank  --- I already saw https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20457038/how-to-round-to-2-decimals-with-python and did not see the solution (hence this question).  Downvote?  Really??

Comment: @Błotosmętek -- thank you!  I actually tried "Start: {self.data_start[0].2f}", which threw an error message.  Simple error on my part.  I was missing the colon (":").

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to round to 2 decimals with Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20457038/how-to-round-to-2-decimals-with-python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to append `":.2f"`:

```
self.log(f'BUY - Size: {size}, Cash: {self.getcash():.2f}, Start: {self.data_start[0]:.2f}, End: {self.data_end[0]:.2f}')
```

Originally, I had appended `".2f"` (missing the preceding `":"`), which threw one of the error messages I saw.

Thanks @Błotosmętek!