# convert a large decimal value to a small decimal value

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to  convert 1.368090543211 into 1.36 or 1.3.
please tell me how can I do it.
thank  you.
**I tried this, and the answer is also what I want. But I want a way to shorten a random decimal value.**

## KM_TO_MILES

```
miles = 5.64
def KM_TO_MILES(miles):
    KM = ("{:.2f}" .format(miles * 1.6))
    print(KM , "KM")
```

Comment: I hope to get a simpler and an easy way.

Comment: This works just fine? As does the below answer

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) (you get a badge!) and read through the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. If you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research, post a [Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your attempt and specifically say where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to round to 2 decimals with Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20457038/how-to-round-to-2-decimals-with-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the built-in function [`round`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#round) to round a number.

For example, to round a number to 2 decimals:

```
round(1.368090543211, 2)
```

Result:

```
1.37
```