# Round the answer to 2 decimal points

Tags: python-3.x

I have a function that finds the average of 3 number that are entered by the user on a GUI.  I need to be able to display the answer to 2 decimal points.  I just cant find where to use the round function.

```
def average():
        try:
            value1 = int(month1_entry.get())
            value2 = int(month2_entry.get())
            value3 = int(month3_entry.get())
            cases_average.set((value1 + value2 + value3) / 3)
            
        except ValueError:
            messagebox.showerror("Error", "Please Enter a Whole Number")
```

```
average_label = ttk.Label(frame, textvariable = cases_average)
average_label.grid(column = 2, row = 5, sticky = (E))
```

Any help would be appreciated

Thanks

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20457115/7467083

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to round to 2 decimals with Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20457038/how-to-round-to-2-decimals-with-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [round](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#round) function

```
def average():
        try:
            value1 = int(month1_entry.get())
            value2 = int(month2_entry.get())
            value3 = int(month3_entry.get())
            cases_average.set(round((value1 + value2 + value3) / 3,2)) # I have changed here
            
        except ValueError:
            messagebox.showerror("Error", "Please Enter a Whole Number")
```