# how to round this into 4 decimal places

Tags: python

```
print("\033[2;89H ", force * math.sin(math.radians(degree)))
```

The force `* math.sin(math.radians(degree)` is what I needed to be rounded to 4 decimal places

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to round to 2 decimals with Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20457038/how-to-round-to-2-decimals-with-python)

Comment: While the example is a `print()` call (formatting just for output), rounding for further processing given in the linked question is a different topic.