# How to round in python? example, 45.722 to 45.72, 45.0 to 45.00

Tags: python, rounding

I wanna round after decimal point. I know that the function `round` does it but when the number has only zeros after decimal point I also wanna keep the amount of zeros that I want, becouse python leaves only 1 zero.

```py
round(54.983839,2) == 54.98
round(54.0, 2) == 54.0    # and here I want 54.00
```

Comment: have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/455612/limiting-floats-to-two-decimal-points

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20457038/how-to-round-to-2-decimals-with-python

Comment: It sounds like what you really want to do is *format* the number with two decimal digits for display purposes. `round` is an actual mathematical calculation, and it can't give you `54.00` instead of `54.0` because *they are not different things*.

Comment: Well, both rounding and format, and yes 54.00 = 54.0 but for Competitive programming purposes I needed exactly 2 digits after decimal point not matter what type of digits.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `format()`:

```
print(format(54.0, ".2f"))
```

The output will be:

```
54.00
```

Comment: No need to use both `round` _and_ `format`: the format call already does the rounding, so `format(54.0, ".2f")` is enough.

Answer (score 0):

Use string formatting in python: `"%.2f" % (54.0)`.