# Format float to 4 decimal places without string conversion

Tags: python, python-3.x

Given a float, I want to format it to display only the first 4 decimal places.
(For example, given 12.345678 => I need 12.3456)

However, I'd like to do it in optimal complexity, so I'm aiming to avoid converting the float to string.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: If you're displaying it, you will need to convert it a string anyway.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20457284/14265469

Comment: You sure you want to truncate `12.345678` to `12.3456` instead of rounding to `12.3457`?

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).
“Show me how to solve this coding problem” is not a Stack Overflow issue.  We expect you to make an honest attempt, and *then* ask a *specific* question about your algorithm or technique.
Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing documentation and tutorials.
You need to look up how to format, round, truncate, ... float output.  We expect you to include that searching in your posted question.

Answer (score 2):

Use floor (numpy) to just display the first 4 decimals, however not rounding:

```
np.floor(12.345678*10000)/10000
```

Out:

```
12.3456
```

Use round() just to round down to 4 decimal places:

```
round(12.345678,4)
```

Out:
12.3457

Comment: The OP specified 12.3456 as expected output, but your code gives 12.3457

Comment: In that case: np.floor(12.345678 *10000)/10000.

Comment: @JohnMommers Update your answer with that option as well so future readers will not miss it as it is just in the comments at the moment :-)