# How ToFixed Eight Time In Python

Tags: python-3.x

I Have this Time Format In Js

result

```
631037399054.2473
```

js code

```
Date.now() + parseFloat(Math.random().toFixed(8))
```

How Can I Do It In Python

Comment: what is your desired outout?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20457038/how-to-round-to-2-decimals-with-python) answer your question?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to round to 2 decimals with Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20457038/how-to-round-to-2-decimals-with-python)