# How to round up a decimal properly in python(or django)

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, django-views

I was trying to round UP a decimal with the code I found below, but it doesn't seem to work properly in python(django). Here is the code:

```
import math
def round_up(n, decimals=0):
    multiplier = 10 ** decimals
    return math.ceil(n * multiplier) / multiplier
```

Here are some of the results I get when I run the function:

```
print(round_up(20.232, 2))
print(round_up(20.211, 2))
print(round_up(20.4, 2))

20.24
20.22
20.4
```

However, for some reason, I get a weird value when I input 80.4. I am getting 80.41 instead of 80.4:

```
print(round_up(80.4, 2))
80.41
```

Is there any other way I can round up decimals in python(django)? I have gotten this off the internet, so there might be some other problems other than the one I mentioned above(inputting 80.4). Basically, I just want to round up a decimal to the second decimal point like above(but of course rounding up 80.4 or 20.3 would just be 80.4 and 20.3 respectively). Thank you, and please leave any questions you have.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to round to 2 decimals with Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20457038/how-to-round-to-2-decimals-with-python)

Comment: Not exactly. The link is for round(). I am trying to round UP.

Comment: Your problem comes from a floating point error. Try 
print(80.4 * (10 ** 2)) and see by yourself why this is not working.

Comment: @DanielP Could you please write the code in the format print(round_up(decimal, number))? If possible, I would appreciate it if you can write the full functioning code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem occurs when you multiply float numbers

```
>>> 80.4 * 100
8040.000000000001
```

So, `math.ceil(80.4 * 100) == 8041`

If you wanna be precise, you could use [Decimal](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html)

```
from decimal import Decimal, ROUND_CEILING

def round_up_decimal(n, decimals=0):
    multiplier = Decimal(10 ** decimals)
    return (n * multiplier).to_integral(rounding=ROUND_CEILING) / multiplier

print(round_up_decimal(Decimal("20.232"), 2))
print(round_up_decimal(Decimal("20.0"), 2))
print(round_up_decimal(Decimal("20.4"), 2))

print(round_up_decimal(Decimal("80.4"), 2))
```

Output

```
20.24
20
20.4
80.4
```

Also, you can create another function to work with float

```
def round_up_float(n, decimals=0):
    return float(round_up_decimal(Decimal(str(n)), decimals)) # uses previous function


print(round_up_float(20.232, 2))
print(round_up_float(20.0, 2))
print(round_up_float(20.4, 2))

print(round_up_float(80.4, 2))
```

Output

```
20.24
20.0
20.4
80.4
```

Comment: Thank you for your clear answer. However, may I ask the difference between a decimal and a float? Which one should I be using?

Comment: @codebuilder decimal stores your number 'as is', respecting all digits. float instead can slightly change your numbers as you get at `80.4 * 100 == 8040.000000000001`.   Decimals are a little bit slower and require more complex syntax than float.  So, If you store money or something precise-needed I think you should use Decimals. If you store distance or volume you can use float. But be aware of rounding errors like you've got.

Answer (score 1):

I may have misunderstood your question, but as far as I understand, I wanted to write it in case it helps.

---

Have you tried the **round()** function already available in Python?

```
round(20.232, 2)
round(20.0, 2)
round(20.4, 2)
round(80.4, 2)

20.23
20.0
20.4
80.4
```

I say it again, I answered as far as I understand, of course, this is a ready-made function and it may not be what you want, but if it helps, I would be glad.