# Tip calculator rounding to 2 decimal places in Python

Tags: python

I am having a problem with rounding the final result to 2 decimal places in Python.
It always shows up only 1 decimal. eg 33.6$
I want to have it as 33.60$

```
    #tip calculator
bill = float (input("what is the total bill? "))
tip = float (input ("percentage tip 10%, 20% etc. ? "))
ppl = int (input ("number of people to split the bill? "))

tip_decimal = tip/100+1
calc = (bill/ppl)*tip_decimal
calc2 = round(calc, 2)
print(f"each person should pay {calc2}$")
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to round to 2 decimals with Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20457038/how-to-round-to-2-decimals-with-python)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use formating here.

```py
bill = float (input("what is the total bill? "))
tip = float (input ("percentage tip 10%, 20% etc. ? "))
ppl = int (input ("number of people to split the bill? "))

tip_decimal = tip/100+1
calc = (bill/ppl)*tip_decimal # change calc2 to calc in print
# calc2 = round(calc, 2) # you also not need this line of code.
print(f"each person should pay {calc:.2f}$") # here `:.2f` add zero at end if there is no second digit
```

Comment: The `round` function is not needed. Simple use `calc` instead of `calc2`.

Comment: @Justin This is in OP's code.

Comment: @Justin Anyway Thanks, I have change it.