# How to round numbers in place in a string in python

Tags: python, rounding

I'd like to take some numbers that are in a string in python, round them to **2 decimal spots** in place and return them.  So for example if there is:

```
"The values in this string are 245.783634 and the other value is: 25.21694"
```

I'd like to have the string read:

```
"The values in this string are 245.78 and the other value is: 25.22"
```

Comment: Likely dupe of [How to round to 2 decimals with Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20457038/how-to-round-to-2-decimals-with-python) ..

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative using regex for what it is worth:

```
import re

def rounder(string, decimal_points):
    fmt = f".{decimal_points}f"
    return re.sub(r'\d+\.\d+', lambda x: f"{float(x.group()):{fmt}}", string)

text = "The values in this string are 245.783634 and the other value is: 25.21694"

print(rounder(text, 2))
```

#### Output:

```
The values in this string are 245.78 and the other value is: 25.22
```

Answer (score 0):

What you'd have to do is find the numbers, round them, then replace them. You can use regular expressions to find them, and if we use [`re.sub()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub), it can take a function as its "replacement" argument, which can do the rounding:

```
import re

s = "The values in this string are 245.783634 and the other value is: 25.21694"

n = 2
result = re.sub(r'\d+\.\d+', lambda m: format(float(m.group(0)), f'.{n}f'), s)
```

Output:

```
The values in this string are 245.78 and the other value is: 25.22
```

Here I'm using the most basic regex and rounding code I could think of. You can vary it to fit your needs, for example check if the numbers have a sign (regex: `[-+]?`) and/or use something like the [`decimal`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html) module for handling large numbers better.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure quite what you are trying to do. "Round them in place and return them" -- do you need the values saved as variables that you will use later? If so, you might look into using a regular expression (as noted above) to extract the numbers from your string and assign them to variables.

But if you just want to be able to format numbers on-the-fly, have you looked at f-strings? [f-string](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/)

```
print(f"The values in this string are {245.783634:.2f} and the other value is: {25.21694:.2f}.")
```

output:

```
The values in this string are 245.78 and the other value is: 25.22.
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use format strings simply

```
link=f'{23.02313:.2f}'
print(link)
```

This is one hacky way but many other solutions do exist. I did that in one of my recent projects.