# round decimal numbers in Python

Tags: python, decimal

How can I render decimal numbers in Python? For example, in the number `3.14373873` only up to and including the number 4.

I want to round the decimal numbers from a specific place:

As example:

```
3.14373873 -> 3.14
```

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20457038/how-to-round-to-2-decimals-with-python?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Limiting floats to two decimal points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/455612/limiting-floats-to-two-decimal-points)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use the round() function:

https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_round.asp

Example:

```
p = round(50.12345,3)
print(p)
```

Output:

```
 50.123
```

Example 2:

```
# for integers
print(round(15))

# for floating point
print(round(51.6))
print(round(51.5))
print(round(51.4))
```

Output:

```
15  
52  
52  
51
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
print(round(3.14373873, 4))
```

Answer (score 0):

The round function from the standard python library can be used to round floats to the desired number of digits after decimal point -:

```
round(decimal_num, num_of_digits_to_round_to)
```

To round `3.14373873` to just `3.14`, you can do the following -:

```
round(3.14373873, 2)
```

Refer to [official python wiki](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#round) for more info -:

> **round(number, ndigits=None)**
>
> *Return number rounded to ndigits precision
> after the decimal point. If ndigits is omitted or is None, it returns
> the nearest integer to its input.*

Answer (score 0):

you can use the round() function:-

***Example :***

x = round(1.54321, 2)

print(x)

- You can mention the value after the how many digits you have to store on your program
- Your output will be 1.54 because of the mention of 2 digits...
- If you have mentioned 3 digits then the output will be 1.543 like that

Comment: Note that `ROUND` function had also been proposed in the 3 other answers (which were also posted prior to this answer)